# How to avoid query duplication when using view composers?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1.

I have many views which somehow included in each other. For example, I have the main layout, some modal windows, some custom pages. So basically I have N views.

Let me show you a concrete example. The `layout.blade.php` is basic layout. The `companies/index.blade.php` is company list. The `modals/companies/create.blade.php` is a modal template which is included in layout.

Imagine I have a list of company industries. I need to provide the list to  the `modals/companies/create.blade.php` and to the `companies/index.blade.php`. The list shouldn't be passed from the controller, because it's kind of code duplication and the list is not related to any conditions, so I don't want to pollute controllers with the same lines of code.

So I have a view composer service provider where I link view composers to views. I may have two approaches:

1. Each view composer represents small part of data, like "IndustriesViewComposer" which serves industry list
2. Each view composer represents all data necessary for some view, like "CreateCompanyModalViewComposer"

When I tried the first way my service provide file looked like:

```
'App\ViewComposers\IndustriesViewComposer' => [
    'modals.companies.create',
    'modals.companies.edit'
    ... some other views ...
],
```

In this case if some of the views are included in the same view the query which retrieves industry list will be duplicated. So if I have many small view composers and corresponding views, then the queries are duplicated in case I include those views together. Since I have many modals which are included together I get the duplication.

In the second way I have exactly one view composer for one view. Same situation happens here. For example, I know that I need to provide industry list for company creation modal, and the same list I need to provide to company edition modal.

View sharing for composers won't work since I need to provide the data only for specific pages for users who is logged in.

So basically the question is: how to execute one query for multiple views in case the views are rendering in the current request and avoid duplication.

Imagine I have a single company page. 
1) In every page of my system I have company creation modal which needs industries list
2) In single company page I include company edition modal which needs industries list
3) Single page also need industries list

How to retrieve the list only once and provide it to single view, new company modal and edit company modal views?

Comment: you cant simply create a method in a model that executes the querys? or are you looking for something sexier?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a middleware. In the middleware you make a query and save the model (or collection) with a bind to IoC Container.

So, in your middleware you can do (for example):

```
$my_data = Data::where('some_field','some_value')->first();

App::instance('my_data_saved', $my_data);
```

do not forget to include the `use App;`

After that you can access the data where you want (controllers, views, etc.) with IoC Container, for example:

```
<title>{{ App::make('my_data_saved')->title }}</title>
```

Then you only need include the middleware in your routes or controllers where need the data for your views.

Comment: I know my comment is late but this isn't respecting the design pattern that should be used within a Laravel app. You better consider binding an app singleton, more informations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#binding-basics